# Microsoft .NET Chart Control (3.5) - Remove gap for missing x-axis value

Tags: .net, charts, controls

Say you have the following series:
(2006, 1)
(2007, 5)
(2009, 3)
(2010, 8)

If this series is plotted as a column chart, then there is a massive gap between the x-axis points 2007 and 2009.

So is there a way to specify that the chart control should not leave a gap for data that it thinks should have been there?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem in the past when working with Dundas Charts which has been re-used by Microsoft for the .Net Charting components.
With Dundas you need to set the Series.XValueIndexed property to "false". This property does not exist in .Net charting, but there is a Series.IsXValueIndexed property which seems to be quite similar. Maybe you should try set this to false and see what happens.

Comment: Hey :) It turns out that Series.IsXValueIndexed is a step in the right direction; but it needs to be set to true to solve the problem. Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: Indeed, false is the default value, my mistake.